# Newbie to Github: how to view work in progress

Tags: git, github, workflow

I'm pretty new to coding, so am trying to explore and learn as much as possible. I've been playing around with Github and exploring some more complex repos (the team is using Django and React) - how can you load this more complex code to see a work in progress? For HTML and CSS I understand how you can load a work in progress and see how things are going, but I'm completely lost with these more robust repos with a lot of different languages and files going on.

I tried downloading the repo and just reading through the code, and just tried playing around to see if I can load the website, but nothing was working...

Comment: Repositories for libraries and other open source stuff usually have a doc section containing instructions for contributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the readme.md file in the github repository, in that file should be the step to get the project running in your localhost, normally is pretty straightforward

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I checked the readme.md file, and it was just a one-line description of what the project is. Would there be an alternative course of action?